# Lifting up state for React app with several layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have an application to create a company with the following structure:

```
-- CompanyForm
   |-- DepartmentForm
       |-- EmployeeForm
           |-- EntryForm
           |-- BadgeForm
```

It is a complex nested form that is built from all the components above. It represents the following relationships:

- Company has many departments
- Department has many employees
- Employees have many entries
- Employees have one badge
  I've been trying to implement the state management, but have found it a little tricky. These are my options:

1. Use React context (trying to avoid doing this to keep the complexity of the project low and avoid using global states)
2. Have the CompanyForm component hold all of the state, and pass down update/delete handlers to the child components.
   Initially, this seemed like the best option, so that the CompanyForm would be the one source of truth. However, since each form has so many fields (department has 3, employee has 6, entries have 4, etc...)

```
const CompanyForm = (props) => {
   const [departments, setDepartments] = useState<Map<number, Department>>(new Map())
...
return (<DepartmentForm departmentData={data} setName={setName}, setDescription={setDescriontion} setDate={setDate} ...>)
}
```

This became messy for a couple reasons:

- I would have to give DepartmentForm more than 30 props (of set handlers), and that just didn't seem right
- Instead of holding an array, I had a map that indexed departments by id so that the handlers (ex: setName) could find the right department object

3. Have the CompanyForm component hold all of the state, but also have the subcomponents hold some state and high level handlers

```
const CompanyForm = (props) => {
   const [departments, setDepartments] = useState<Map<number, Department>>(new Map())
...
return (<DepartmentForm departmentData={data} setDepartmentData={setDepartmentData} setEmployeeData={setEmployeeData} ...>)
}

const DepartmentForm = (props) => {
   const [employees, setEmployees] = useState<Map<number, Employee>>(new Map())
...
return (<EmployeeForm employeeData={data} setEmployeeData={props.setEmployeeData}...>)
}
```

so instead of having handlers that would update every single field, I would have handlers that update the entire object (setDepartmentData, setEmployeeData). However, that means I need to have state in the subcomponents, which I dislike

I am not really sure how to handle this. Lifting up the state with a project with 3 layers has proven to be difficult. I got it working with approach #3, but it seems really messy and confusing. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: You probably need a global state solution, like context, redux, etc. You said that don't want to use context to avoid complexity, but sounds like you have much more complexity trying to pass the states.
Global state may seem scary at first, but if done it right, it will make your app more simple actually (in this specific scenario that you described).

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro is it a bad practice to use global state? I come from a strongly typed language (Java) and always tried to stay away from globals/statics

Comment: It's not a bad practice to use global state in React applications. It's actually a standard in most apps at the moment. The trick is to decide what should be a global state and what should be a local state. Personally, I like to start with local state and only move things to global state as needed (if it becomes too nested, for example).
If this is a new thing to you, I would suggest you take a look at RecoilJS, which is a simple state management tool made by Facebook. Redux is another popular option, but more complex in my opinion.